# How to authenticate with Passport JS via a Chrome Extension

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome-extension, passport.js

I have a chrome extension that will allow users to make a POST request to my Express server. If the user has already logged in via Passport on the server's domain, how could they be logged in via the request made by the extension?

Normally on the server's domain, all the user's authentication data is saved by Passport to a `req.user` object.

This object is `undefined` when a request is made to the server from the extension:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/extension',
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  data: {'test': 1},
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('Success!');
  }
});
```

`req.user` is set by Passport JS on the server:

> If authentication succeeds, the next handler will be invoked and the
>   req.user property will be set to the authenticated user.
>   [Passport Docs](http://passportjs.org/docs)

Comment: Where does the `req.user` object exist? Is it on the server, or the client? Is is that the user has already logged in *in a web page*, not your extension? Is this `req.user` a JavaScript Object that exists in a web page?

Comment: Updated my question. `req.user` is set by Passport on the server. It looks like this object is not remembered in a request sent from the extension.